# Mendeley: how to add document from bibliography entry?

Tags: publications, citations, reference-managers

I'm starting to write my bachelor thesis. It's my first time ever using citation software to manage the citations in the document and to generate the bibliography at the end of the document. So bear with me if my question is totally wrong.

Basically I added an image to my thesis. I found the image in paper A which in turn referenced the image from another paper B. Now I need to reference this original paper B.

[This is the image on paper A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8rQD.png)

[Bibliography entry on paper A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB03y.png)

Now I need that exact bibliography entry in my thesis. I'm using Mendeley. I could manually enter the author names, the title etc.

But I'm wondering if there is a way to submit the entire entry and automatically add the document to Mendeley. After all the entry has all the necessary information to add the document and it is well separated by periods that identify each part of the citation.

So do I need to manually enter the document or can Mendeley automatically add it from the entry (second image above)?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to `Add` --> `Add Entry Manually` you can populate the fields for the PMID or DOI of the paper you want to add to the library and Mendeley will populate all the other fields accordingly. You simply need to find the correct entry for the paper in a search engine (e.g., PubMed, GoogleScholar, Journal Webpage, ...).